# Where is the source code of PHP intl NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT?

Tags: php, numberformatter

Where can I find the PHP source code behind [NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) ?

```php
$f = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
echo $f->format(456);

// four hundred fifty-six
```

I don't find the algorithm of `NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT` in these links:

- https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/intl/formatter
- https://github.com/symfony/intl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as the intl extension is just a binding to the C ICU library you will find here what you are looking for:

https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/search?q=spellout&unscoped_q=spellout